# Stack In C - incompatible type 'int'

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I have this code right here. I'm trying to implement but I got and error and I've not idea how I can get rid of it. It's a stack. I gotta call the function to insert the values in it but the compiler keeps showing this error and don't let me do anything else.

`Passing 'pilha' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'`

```
pilha * cria_pilha(){
    pilha *pi;
    pi = malloc(sizeof(pilha));

    if (!pi) {
        pi -> topo = 0;
    }
    return pi;

}
```

and I'm trying to call it here.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    //Cria vetor de struct preenchido com a quantidade MAX_ELEMENTOS
    pilha * pi = cria_pilha();
    pilha p[MAX_ELEMENTOS] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                             6, 7, 8, 9, 10};


    //Call the function Stack, then pass by argument p[]
    //stacking the values MAX_ELEMENTS times.

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        //The error happens here. I already identified the cause but
        //I've got no idea how to solve it. Any help please?
        empilha(pi, p[i]);  --  Passing 'pilha' to parameter of incompatible type 'int'
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        desempilha(pi);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function `int empilha(pilha *pi, int p);` which, by my understanding has pilha *pi that is no compatible with the type of int. How can I solve this issue?

Here's my whole code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_ELEMENTOS 10

typedef struct {
    int elementos[MAX_ELEMENTOS];
    int topo;
} pilha;

pilha * cria_pilha(){
    pilha *pi;
    pi = malloc(sizeof(pilha));

    if (!pi) {
        pi -> topo = 0;
    }
    return pi;

}

int empilha(pilha *pi, int p);
int desempilha(pilha *pi);
int tamanho (pilha *pi);
void destroi(pilha *pi);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]){
    //Cria vetor de struct preenchido com a quantidade MAX_ELEMENTOS
    pilha * pi = cria_pilha();
    pilha p[MAX_ELEMENTOS] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                             6, 7, 8, 9, 10};


    //Chama função empilhar, passa por argumento o velho p[]
    //para função empilha MAX_ELEMENTOS vezes.
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        empilha(pi, p[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
        desempilha(pi);
    }

}

int empilha(pilha *pi, int p){
    if (pi == NULL || pi -> elementos == ((int*)MAX_ELEMENTOS)) {
        printf("Erro, pilha cheia.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    pi -> elementos[pi->topo] = p;
    pi -> topo = pi -> topo + 1;
    return 1;
}

int desempilha(pilha *pi){
    if (pi == NULL || pi -> elementos[0] == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    pi -> topo = pi -> topo -1;
    return pi -> elementos[pi->topo];
}

int tamanho(pilha *pi){
    return pi -> topo;
}

void destroi(pilha *pi){
    free(pi);
}
```

Comment: You should not do this `if (!pi) {
        pi -> topo = 0;
    }` because you would de-reference a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
empilha(pi, p[i]);
```

the second argument has the type `pilha` due to this declaration

```
pilha p[MAX_ELEMENTOS] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                         6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

but the function expects an argument of the type `int`

```
int empilha(pilha *pi, int p);
```

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea to name identifiers using non-English words. The code in such a case is unreadable.

Also using initializers without braces to initialize aggregates makes the code error-prone and unclear.

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
pilha *pi;
pi = malloc(sizeof(pilha));

if (!pi) {
    pi -> topo = 0;
}
```

when the `if()` is true, then the call to `malloc()` failed and `pi` contains NULL.

when the call to `malloc()` fails, then `pi -> topo = 0;` is trying to write to an address just above address 0x00.

This results in undefined behavior and the assignment should result in a seg fault event.

regarding:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ELEMENTOS; i++) {
    empilha(pi, p[i]);
}
```

this code block and the function: `empilha()` can be replaced with:

```
memcpy( pi->elementos, p, MAX_ELEMENTOS * sizeof( int ));
```

OT: in function: `empilha()`, this:

```
if (pi == NULL || pi -> elementos == ((int*)MAX_ELEMENTOS)) {
    printf("Erro, pilha cheia.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

should already have been checked before calling this function.

OT: regarding:

```
printf("Erro, pilha cheia.\n");
```

error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Suggest:

```
fprintf( stderr, "Erro, pilha cheia.\n");
```

regarding the expression:

```
((int*)MAX_ELEMENTOS)
```

this is the same as:

```
int *10;
```

Definitely not what you want and this verifies nothing